# Navigating to a new page through Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I navigate to another webpage using the same driver with Selenium in python?
I do not want to open a new page. I want to keep on using the same driver.
I thought that the following would work:

```
driver.navigate().to("https://support.tomtom.com/app/contact/")
```

But it doesn't! Navigate seems not to be a 'WebDriver'  method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To navigate to a webpage you just write

```
driver.get(__url__)
```

you can do this in your program multiple times

Answer (score 2):

The line of code which you have tried as :

```
driver.navigate().to("https://support.tomtom.com/app/contact/")
```

It is a typical *Java* based line of code.

However as per the currect **Python API Docs** of [The WebDriver implementation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver) **navigate()** method is yet to be supported/implemented.

Indtead, you can use the **get(url)** method instead which is defined as :

```
def get(self, url):
    """
    Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    """
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
```

Comment: Actually when I run get(url), a new window pops up

Comment: As per the _Selenium Java Client_ implementation `get()`/`navigate().to()` invokes the same call. It would be wiser to deal with the popups.

Comment: @user3623123: if you say you get a new window everytime you call `get`, please update your question with a [mcve]. I do not think you should be getting that behavior so maybe the problem is in how you are using it.

Comment: From what I have experienced, .get() behaves more like creating a new browser instance that will forget/delete all previous cookies and sessions. This is bad if you are logged in somewhere and try to navigate to a different page.