# Selenium webdriver clears cookies when navigating to new domain

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

#options.add_argument('-headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", options=options)

browser.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/")
print browser.title
browser.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys("admin")
browser.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("hunter2")
browser.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()
print browser.get_cookies()
print 'loading another page: ' + url
#example url = example.com
browser.get(url)
```

I'm trying to do an automated test involving CORS. So, my requirement is I login to domain A successfully and get some cookies set. This works, and I see the cookies set when I do `get_cookies()`. Next, I navigate to another domain B, which makes a CORS request to domain A (all CORS headers are properly set, and tested manually). But this request fails because it appears that when I navigate to domain B, the cookies are cleared, so the request is unsuccessful.

Is there any way to force cookies to not clear ?

Note : same behavior with Chrome and Firefox driver on OSX

Comment: Where are u declaring url? where are u checking new url cookies?

Comment: can you check manually if the cookie is per session, meaning when you navigate to siteB session from siteA is terminated and cookie got deleted.

Comment: @DarkSuniuM : URL is obtained as a param to the function (not shown here)
Checking the cookies is done manually since i'm not running this headless (for testing)

Comment: @Infern0 - In the chrome process that is opened by driver, the cookies are not cleared if I test manually. it appears that, it only gets cleared by selenium when `browser.get(url)
` is called and URL is a different domain.

Comment: @asudhak You havn't provided any information for us to do our analysis. Can you update the question with your binary information and the _Manual Steps_ you are trying to _Automate_ along with the relevant _HTML_ and the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Use `browser.navigate().to(url)` instead of `get()`.

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42465954/4536543

Comment: Not available in Python

Comment: yeah, it's not implemented in Python, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49355539/4536543