# Redirect to Final url from selenium failing

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, redirect

**Requirement**

Get the Final Url after redirect chain like it happens on the normal browser using selenium .
The urls are article urls got from twitter.

***Behavior on normal Desktop browser after viewing the redirect and headers:***

- The Url is a twitter URL which gets a `301 error -moved permanently`
- Then it follows the location tag to a shortened url which then again gets a 302 error .
- It again follows the redirect chain and lands on the final page.

**Behavior using Selenium**

- It *redirects finally to the main website homepage/index rather than the actual article page*  .Final url is not the same as actual one.

**Initial basic code**

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent= Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0');
#above user agent is an example but multiple different user agents were tried 
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(driver_loaction,chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(45)
browser.get(url)
final_url = browser.current_url
```

**Various attempts to get the final url instead of the main website home/index page**

1. With normal wait

`browser.get(url)`

`time.sleep(25)`

2. With WebDriverWait-

   `WebDriverWait(browser,20)`
3. with expected_conditions

   `WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.url_contains("portion of the final url"))`

ends up timing out everytime , even with different conditions like url_to_be etc.

**Behavior on Trying with non-selenium options**

1.Wget -

Below is response from a wget call edited for obscuring actual details -

> Resolving t.co (t.co)...,
>
> ... Connecting to t.co (t.co)|:443... connected. HTTP
>
> request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently Location:
>
> [following]
>
> Resolving domain (domain)...
>
> ... Connecting to ... connected.
>
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found Location:
>
> [following]
>
> --Date--   Resolving website (website)... ip ,
>
> connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

As seen finally we got the homepage rather than the website page .

2. Request library -

   `response = requests.get(Url, allow_redirects=True, headers=self.headers, timeout=30)`

(header contains user agents but tried with actual same request headers from browser that gets the proper final url response )- gets the homepage --

checking redirects by `response.history`  we see that from t.co(twitter url ) - we redirect to  the short url then redirect to website  homepage and end .

3. urlib library -
   same final response.

---

Test e.g url - `t.co/Mg3IYF8ZLm?amp=1`   (add the https:// - i removed for posting)

After days of different approaches , i am stuck -- i somehow think that selenium is key to resolve this because it works on normal desktop browsers then should work with selenium - right?

Edit: It seems it is happening with other versions of drivers and selenium too ,it would be great if we could at least find out the actual reasoning  its happening with certain links like the example given .

Comment: Increase the `browser.set_page_load_timeout(120)` this should work.

Comment: @KunduK did not work unfortunately .i am open to more suggestions ,

Comment: Strange I have checked it working while increase the timeout.Which chrome driver version are you using?

Comment: chromedriver : 2.24.1
google-chrome-stable -version : Google Chrome 71.0.3578.98
python2.7 
on my aws linux server .

Comment: Seems it is very old.Try Chrome Driver version 78.You can download from following link.https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: @KunduK , can you tell me which version of driver  and chrome you used to get the final article url and were the chrome_options the same as above?

it might help me debug

Comment: @KunduK tried with the latest versions ,still not working as expected , can you provide the arguments you passed please with the chrome_options

Comment: @TaherKhalil I have a similar problem with headless chrome. I know its an old topic, but did you manage to get it to work eventually?

Comment: @DirkN.  i attempt with a retry logic with different user-agent randomly from a list with the following options,chrome_options.add_argument('network.http.connection-retry-timeout = 250');
chrome_options.add_argument('network.http.connection-timeout= 90');
 chrome_options.add_argument('network.http.max-connections =  900');
   chrome_options.add_argument('network.http.keep-alive.timeout = 115');
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
  chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

after which i use a fallback to wget .Try it

Answer (score 0):

The issue was after the intermediate url, the url cannot redirect to the final page due to the missing headers, the intermediate url (http://www.cumhuriyet.com.tr/) is blocked with 403 status code.

Once we add the headers for the request the url is navigating to the final url.

I have given the Java implementation below. Sorry, I am not familiar with this code in Python. Please convert this code to python and it may solve the issue.

```
  @Test
  public void RUN() {
    BrowserMobProxy proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
    proxy.start(0);
    Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);
    proxy.addRequestFilter((request, contents, messageInfo)->{
        request.headers().add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        request.headers().add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        return null;
    });

    String proxyOption = "--proxy-server=" + seleniumProxy.getHttpProxy();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.addArguments(proxyOption);


    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","<driverLocation>");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);


    driver.get("<url>");
    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
}
```

Comment: Navigate.to doesn't work for me , it throws a `webdriver has no attribute called navigate` , after some checking it seems this is a java implementation not yet ported to python - check https://stackoverflow.com/a/49355539/5867761

Comment: If you have an implementation in python please do share.

Comment: thanks but i have already tried the wait , you can see the attempt i have mentioned in the question itself .

Comment: Thanks again ,but its not strange that when you comment headless  it works , as it opens a actual browser in a background in that case and unfurls the url from there , 
but u cant use that on a server,  as there is no proper  browsers on servers ,

Comment: I have updated the code to work in headless mode. I am sorry, I don't know the above code in python.

Answer (score 0):

I have used your code only.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent= Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0');
#above user agent is an example but multiple different user agents were tried
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(120)
browser.get("url")
final_url = browser.current_url
print(final_url)
```

**Snapshot**:

[image]

Comment: Ah! that is the same i am getting but its not the right one ,  open that short url (twitter url)  on normal browser and check the final url .

perhaps i wasn't clear enough while explaining -  

as you see you are getting the homepage url of the website rather than the actual article url which its supposed to go to , which is  -  http://www.cumhuriyet.com.tr/haber/turkiye/1704484/metrobuste-yeni-uygulama.html  -- 

Hence it is not redirecting to final actual page but loosing its way somewhere in between .

Comment: its ok : thanks for your effort , any idea why this might be happening ?